# How to combine UIViewRepresentable and instance methods for Mapkit?

Tags: swiftui, mapkit, mkmapview, uiviewrepresentable

For an app I need to display a Map from mapkit.
I'm using SwiftUI.
On top of the Map itself there need to be a search function and when you finish the search (enter) the map moves the visible region to the result of the search

```
import MapKit
import SwiftUI


struct MapViewTwo: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    let location: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    let annotationItems: [MyAnnotationItem]
    @State   var searchText = ""
    @State private var region: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(
        center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: MapDefaults.latitude, longitude: MapDefaults.longitude),
        span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: MapDefaults.zoomedOut, longitudeDelta: MapDefaults.zoomedOut))
    
    private enum MapDefaults {
        static let latitude = 51.507222
        static let longitude = -0.1275
        static let zoomedOut = 2.0
        static let zoomedIn = 0.01
    }
    
    func searchMap(){
        let searchRequest = MKLocalSearch.Request()
        searchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery =   searchText // This is where you can pass in you search string parameter.
        searchRequest.resultTypes = .address
        
 
        let search = MKLocalSearch(request: searchRequest)
        search.start { response, error in
            guard let response = response else {
                print("Error: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error").")
                return
            }
            print("Found \(response.mapItems.count)")
            region = response.boundingRegion
        }
    }
    
 
    var body: some View {
        Map(coordinateRegion: $region,
            interactionModes: .all,
            showsUserLocation: true,
            annotationItems: annotationItems) { item in
            MapPin(coordinate: item.coordinate)
        }
     
        ZStack(alignment:.top){
            VStack(alignment:.leading){
                
                HStack {
                    Circle()
                        .fill(.white)
                        .frame(width: 44, height: 44)
                        .overlay(   Image(systemName: "arrow.backward"))
                        .onTapGesture(){
                            print("Back button")
                        }
                    
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                        TextField("search", text: $searchText, onEditingChanged: { isEditing in
                            
                        }, onCommit: {
                            print ("Search for \(searchText)")
                            searchMap()
                            
                        })
                        .foregroundColor(.primary)
                        .textInputAutocapitalization(.never)
                        
                        Button(action: {
                            self.searchText = ""
                            //BACK TO NORMAL
                            
                        }) {
                            Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill").opacity(searchText == "" ? 0 : 1)
                        }
                        
                        
                    }
                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 8, leading: 6, bottom: 8, trailing: 6))
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    .background(Color(.secondarySystemBackground))
                    .cornerRadius(10.0)
                }
                
                
            }.padding(.top,50).padding(.leading,20).padding(.trailing,20)
            
            
        }
        //MARK: User location button
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom){
            VStack(alignment:.trailing){
                Spacer()
                HStack{
                    Spacer()
                    Circle()
                        .fill(.white)
                        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                        .overlay(   Image( "user-location"))
                        .onTapGesture(){
                            
                            region  = MKCoordinateRegion(
                                center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 50.96847915649414, longitude: 5.982074737548828),
                                span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: MapDefaults.zoomedOut, longitudeDelta: MapDefaults.zoomedOut))
                            
                            
                            
                        }
                }.padding(.bottom,100).padding(.trailing,30)
                
            }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .onAppear(perform: setupLocation)
    }
    
    func setupLocation() {
        region = MKCoordinateRegion(
            center: location,
            span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: MapDefaults.zoomedIn, longitudeDelta: MapDefaults.zoomedIn))
    }
}
```

I also need to have the functionality that a user can drop a pin on the map (center) and select the pin and move it to a different location. When he does, the GLGeocoder will reverse geocode the location and provide this feedback on some Text elements.

For this I have the following code (playgrounds).

1. TryView (my view to display the DropApinMapView and search bar
2. DropAPinMapView handling the drag and drop and geocoding

```
#TryView.swift

import SwiftUI
import MapKit
struct TryView: View {
    @State var mapItems: [MKMapItem] = []
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    @State var isPinDropped:Bool = false
    @State var showSearchResults:Bool = false
    @State   var searchText = ""
    @State private var showCancelButton: Bool = false
    @State var pinDropDetail  = PinDropDetail(address: "", locality: "", postalCode: "", latitude: 50.96847915649414, longitude: 5.98207473754882, coordinateString: "",isBack: false)
    
 
    @Binding var model: PinDropDetail
    var onDismiss: ((_ model: PinDropDetail) -> Void)?
 
 
    func searchMap(){
        let searchRequest = MKLocalSearch.Request()
        searchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery =   searchText // This is where you can pass in you search string parameter.
        searchRequest.resultTypes = .address
        
        
        let search = MKLocalSearch(request: searchRequest)
        search.start { response, error in
            guard let response = response else {
                print("Error: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error").")
                return
            }
            //NOW I WANT TO MAP TO ANIMATE AND SET THE REGION TO  response.boundingRegion
        }
    }
 
    var body: some View {
        DropAPinMapView(pinDropDetail:self.$pinDropDetail )
            .ignoresSafeArea()
        //MARK: controls
            //search bar
        ZStack(alignment:.top){
            VStack(alignment:.leading){
                HStack {
                    Circle()
                        .fill(.white)
                        .frame(width: 44, height: 44)
                        .overlay(   Image(systemName: "arrow.backward"))
                        .onTapGesture(){
                            print("Back button")
                        }

                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                        TextField("search", text: $searchText, onEditingChanged: { isEditing in

                        }, onCommit: {
                            print ("Search for \(searchText)")
                            searchMap()
                        })
                        .foregroundColor(.primary)
                        .textInputAutocapitalization(.never)

                        Button(action: {
                            self.searchText = ""
                        }) {
                            Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill").opacity(searchText == "" ? 0 : 1)
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 8, leading: 6, bottom: 8, trailing: 6))
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    .background(Color(.secondarySystemBackground))
                    .cornerRadius(10.0)
                }

            }.padding(.top,50).padding(.leading,20).padding(.trailing,20)
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        //MARK: User location button
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom){
            VStack(alignment:.trailing){
                Spacer()
                HStack{
                    Spacer()
                    Circle()
                        .fill(.white)
                        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                        .overlay(   Image( "user-location"))
                        .onTapGesture(){
                            print("Userlocation")
                            
                        }
                }.padding(.bottom,100).padding(.trailing,30)

            }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        //MARK: end of controls
        //IN APP THIS IS A DIFFERENT CONTROL DISPLAYING THE RESULT OF THE PINDROP
        Text(pinDropDetail.address).foregroundColor(.red)
    }
}
```

DropAPinMapView

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit
import Foundation

struct PinDropDetail {
    var address: String
    var locality: String
    var postalCode: String
    var latutide: Double
    var longitude:Double
    var coordinateString: String
    var isBack: Bool
    
    init(address:String,locality:String,postalCode:String,latitude:Double,longitude:Double,coordinateString:String,isBack:Bool){
        self.address = address
        self.locality = locality
        self.postalCode = postalCode
        self.latutide = latitude
        self.longitude = longitude
        self.coordinateString = coordinateString
        self.isBack = isBack
    }
    
}


struct DropAPinMapView: UIViewRepresentable {


    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:50.96847915649414,longitude: 5.98207473754882)
    @Binding var pinDropDetail:  PinDropDetail

    

    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        let map = MKMapView()
        map.mapType = .standard//.hybrid
        map.delegate = context.coordinator
        let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D = coordinate
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.3, longitudeDelta: 0.3))
        map.setRegion(map.regionThatFits(region), animated: true)
        map.showsCompass = true
        map.showsUserLocation = true
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = self.coordinate
        map.addAnnotation(annotation)
        //geocode initial state as well
        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(CLLocation(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude)) { places, error in
            let latitudeString = String(format: "%.5f",coordinate.latitude)
            let longitudeString = String(format: "%.5f", coordinate.longitude)
            self.pinDropDetail.coordinateString = latitudeString + " , " + longitudeString
            self.pinDropDetail.address = (places?.first?.name!)! + ", " + (places?.first?.locality!)!
            self.pinDropDetail.postalCode = (places?.first?.postalCode!)!
            self.pinDropDetail.locality = (places?.first?.locality!)!
            self.pinDropDetail.latutide = coordinate.latitude
            self.pinDropDetail.longitude = coordinate.longitude
        }
        return map
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: Context) {
        
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> DropAPinMapView.Coordinator {
        return DropAPinMapView.Coordinator(parent1: self)
        
    }
    
    final class Coordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
        
        var parent:DropAPinMapView
        init(parent1:DropAPinMapView){
            parent = parent1
        }
        
     
        
        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
            let pin = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "pin")
            pin.isDraggable = true
            pin.pinTintColor = .red
            pin.animatesDrop = true
            return pin
        }
        
        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, didChange newState: MKAnnotationView.DragState, fromOldState oldState: MKAnnotationView.DragState) {
            //print(view.annotation?.coordinate.latitude)
            CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(CLLocation(latitude: (view.annotation?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude: (view.annotation?.coordinate.longitude)!)) { places, error in
                let lat = (view.annotation?.coordinate.latitude)!
                let lon = (view.annotation?.coordinate.longitude)!
                let latitudeString = String(format: "%.5f",lat)
                let longitudeString = String(format: "%.5f", lon)
                self.parent.pinDropDetail.coordinateString = latitudeString + " , " + longitudeString
                self.parent.pinDropDetail.address = (places?.first?.name!)! + ", " + (places?.first?.locality!)!
                self.parent.pinDropDetail.postalCode = places?.first?.postalCode ?? ""
                self.parent.pinDropDetail.locality = places?.first?.locality ?? ""
                self.parent.pinDropDetail.latutide = (view.annotation?.coordinate.latitude)!
                self.parent.pinDropDetail.longitude = (view.annotation?.coordinate.longitude)!
            }
        }
        
        
    }
    
    
}
```

You see two different approaches for the first one (search) simply using a Map and that works. The second problem drop a pin also works but requires to create the UIViewRepresentable

How can I combine the two functionalities in one solution?
It would be great if the DropAPinMapView could be instantiated so a function could be called. I've tried adding a static function which also works but the line

```
let map = MKMapView()
```

Makes the map object private

Please provide solutions, tips or ideas

Answer (score 0):

Inject `MKMapView()` instance from parent. It is a reference type, so parent will be an owner and will be able to work with it while the same reference is used inside representable for rendering.

So it would look like

```
struct TryView: View {
    private let map = MKMapView()   // << owner here !!

    // ...

    var body: some View {
        DropAPinMapView(map: map, pinDropDetail:self.$pinDropDetail ) // << injected

    // ...
    }
}

struct DropAPinMapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let map: MKMapView   // << constructor contract !!

    // ...
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {

        map.mapType = .standard//.hybrid   // << just configure/reset here !!
        // ...
```

Comment: Thanks I'm gonna try this out and let you know

Comment: I've added as you described and in te searchMap function i try to call the following without result map.setRegion(map.regionThatFits(response.boundingRegion), animated: true)

Comment: sorry almost worked can you explain what's missing?